# Show post date on the page

Tags: date

What is the php code for showing post date on the page?

For example, it is a woocommerce product and here is the php code that I have so far:

does this work?

```
   if ($hide_price !== '0') :
        $output .= '<div class="mywoocmmerceprice>';
        $output .= $product->get_categories();  
//here is where I want to add the date                          
        $output .= '</div>';
   endif;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`the_date()`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_date/) is technically the template tag to do it. However it has a somewhat unusual aspect to only output once per date, so if there are multiple posts on page from same date they won't all show it.

[`get_the_date()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_date/) is one level lower and retrieves (not outputs) a post's date without that bit of logic.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Luckily, there will be only one post (or product) per page, and so I think the_date() will work. Would the following work? $output .= $post->get_the_date();

Comment: No, it's a function rather than property of object. It should work in a normal WordPress Loop. Since you are using WooCommerce product you might need to handle it differently, that would be up to specifics of the plugin.